# Can US federal contractors unionize?

Tags: united-states, unions

I was joking with some friends that if the government is allowed to randomly shut down on federal employees they should unionize and randomly shut down the government in return.  This led to someone pointing out that there was apparently a law forbidding federal employees from unionizing?

That got me thinking, what about federal contractors.  Lets say firms X and Y contract with the government to do some sort of work, and the employees of those firms join some multi-firm union.  Would there be anything stopping them from going on strike and shutting down government work dependent on them?

Comment: Side issue: Air traffic controllers are unionized.

Comment: Other federal employees are unionized too.  It is illegal to strike though.  Reagan fired a bunch of ATC when they tried...

Comment: "This led to someone pointing out that there was apparently a law forbidding federal employees from unionizing?": Incorrectly, as it happens.  There is no such law; much of the federal workforce is in fact unionized.

Comment: @phoog Much of the federal workforce is unionized, but some agencies are in fact forbidden from unionizing, and all federal employees are barred from striking (not only is it a firing issue, it’s a criminal offense). Military personnel are also banned from unionizing, it’s a crime to try, and it’s a capital crime for them to go on strike.

Comment: @NateEldredge My comment doesn’t address contractors though.